# Finding the process ID of a process (exclusively) given the process name (not netstat which gives the PIDs of ALL the processes)

Tags: debugging, batch-file, automation, command-prompt, dll-injection

I need to perform the following:

1. Launch firefox
2. Load a page with some plugin content
3. Find the processID of plugin process
4. Attach cdb to the plugin process using the processID
5. Detect DLLs loaded by the plugin

For automatin this using a batch script, I need a way to find the processID given the name of the process. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: console debugger, it is the command line version of windbg

Answer (score 2):

You could use wmic to return that: 
`wmic process where name="cmd.exe"  get processid` gets you pids of all cmd.exe running.
Assuming you do not know full process name (is that's why you could not use `cdb -pn`?) you could also use `like`:
`wmic process where 'name like "%cmd%"'  get processid` will get everything with `cmd` anywhere in it's name. It's also possible to use other SQL wildcards.

To see what properties you can query, open wmic (just do `wmic` from command line) and issue `process get /?`

Note: wmic produces output in Unicode and attaches double `<CR>` to it's output lines. This sometimes requires special attention and handling in your batch.

Comment: What is the case when there are two processes of the same name like two firefox.exe/chrome.exe processes or the two flash player processes when you open a  page with flash content under firefox?

Comment: then you will get both - but anyhow, you need to differentiate those processes using some criteria - what are they? There are many properties you can use to select only the one you're interested in. For example, if you know pid of parent you could use that for selection in addtion to name

Comment: Thanks wmz. But, no, I do not know the process ID of the parent. I have found numerous ways of getting the process IDs of both the processes, but have no way (or don't know of any way) of selecting one of them. That's what I am looking into now. Please let me know if you know any way in which I can do this.

Comment: A quick note for future googlers: Just as ProcessId, `ParentProcessId` is also available in wmic's process "object" (both to query on, and output), so one can in fact figure out parent-child relationships b/w processes (by calling it multiple times in the worst case).